# Insert 1st Element of the array in option value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner, I have a script:

```
var Name = [
['ABCD1234', '555123456'],
['EFGH5678', '111234111'],
['GHIJ9101', '222345222']
];

$(Name).ready( function() {
$(Name).each( function(index, item) {
    var option = ('<option value="'+item+'"></option>');
    $('#GZB').append(option);
});
```

I want to add 1st element of array in the option value in a Datalist ID
also want to change value of the second Input Box value based on the 2nd Element of the array.

Means if "EFGH5678" is selected then second input box value should be 111234111.

Answer Edit:-

```
 const options = [
    ['DL01GB2355', '555123456'],
    ['HR38K1350', '111234111'],
    ['HR38M4985', '222345222']
    ];
// Its is showing both the Option but selecting only one may be because it's an input ID not a Select ID
jQuery( function($){
  const HTMLOptions = options.reduce((html, item) => (html += `<option value="${item[0]}">${item[1]}</option>`, html), "");

$('#KASHIPUR')
.append(HTMLOptions)
//not working
.on('change', function() {
  $("label:contains('Driver Mobile No')").parent().next().find('input').val(this.value);
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const options = [
  ["ABCD1234", "555123456"],
  ["EFGH5678", "111234111"],
  ["GHIJ9101", "222345222"]
];

jQuery( function($) { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope

  // Create a HTMLString using Array.prototype.reduce()
  const HTMLOptions = options.reduce((html, item) => {
     html += `<option value="${item[1]}">${item[0]}</option>`;
     return html;
  }, "");
  
  // Append the generated Options and assign a change listener
  $("#GZB")
    .append(HTMLOptions)
    .on("change", function() {
      $("#GZB_selected").val(this.value);
    })
    .trigger("change"); // Initialize!

});
```

```html
<select id="GZB" name="GZB"></select>
<input id="GZB_selected" name="GZB_selected" type="text">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sir Please see the edited Question